# Angular: persistir retorno de get em função/variavel

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, get, angular-6

```
booksList: Book[];

listById(id: number): Book{
        this.http.get<Book>(`${url}/list/id=${id}`)
        .subscribe((response)=> {
            this.book = response;
            console.log(this.book); //aqui existe o livro
            return this.book; //acho que não está servindo para nada
        });
        console.log(this.book); //aqui não existe
        return this.book; //acho que não está servindo para nada
    }
```

quero persistir o retorno dessa informação em this.book para usar em outras funções, como por exemplo:

```
selectedBook() {
    let myBook = listById(1); (deve me retornar o objeto livro de id 1);
    this.booksList.push(this.book);
    console.log(booksList); //tem que existir o livro 1
}
```

Entanto não consigo, conforme comentei no código a variável sempre aparece como undefined, como fazer o conteúdo do subscribe persistir fora dele?

Agradeço qualquer ajuda.

Comment: Voce tem que retornar o observable e dar o subscribe no seu outro metodo. Vc nao consegue retorna o book direto pois a chamada http é assincrona.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Olá

**Tente fazer o seguinte:**

```
listById(id: number): Book{
      return this.http.get<Book>(`${url}/list/id=${id}`)
}
```

Nessa função, está provavelmente sendo usada a biblioteca **Http** do próprio Angular, a qual retorna uma Observable. As chamadas de serviço geralmente (se não todas) são feitas de forma assíncrona. Então, quando vc chama usando **subscribe**, ele fica "escutando"/esperando o retorno do serviço para então persistir o valor no atributo do qual vc precisa.

**E na sua outra função:**

```
async selectedBook() {
    let myBook = await listById(1).toPromise(); 
    this.booksList.push(this.book);
    console.log(booksList);
}
```

Use async / await para tratar requisições assíncronas de forma mais sucinta e objetiva.
o **.toPromise** é para converter a observable em uma promise, no caso do uso do **async/await**.

Comment: Era exatamente isso, muito obrigada !

Comment: De nada, que bom q funcionou!